# Python3: search csv file for string and return row and column

Tags: python, csv

I have a large csv file, and I am trying to search it for a string. and return the row and column.
The code that I have so far will always return 'nope' for anything that I enter.

The code that I have so far:

```
def search_cell(string):
    with open('aanmaningen.chr', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if string in row:
                print(row[0])
                return row[0]
            else:
                print('nope')
                return 'nope'
```

For example:

When the csv file contains the string 'vve' in row 20, column 9, I want to be able to enter the string 'vve' and get the row and column number back.

Note: because the way the program i'm using exports data, it saves as a character  seperated file (.chr), using the seperator and delimiter ';' essentially a .csv file with a non-standard seperator and delimiter

Comment: Can you please provide example input and expected output?

Comment: What do you mean character separated file? Can you please show an example ?

Comment: Where do you tell the csv.reader that your delimiter is a semicolon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say -

> I have a large csv file, and I am trying to search it for a string. and return the row and column.

That makes me believe that the expected string can be inside a particular column (as a substring) . If so, then what you are doing is wrong.

When you do -

```
for row in reader:
```

`row` is a list of all columns in that particular row. Then when you do -

```
if string in row:
```

It checks if the `string` is completely equal to any column in that row. Instead iterate over the row's columns and check if `string` is in any of the columns and return the row number and column number as a tuple. Use `enumerate` function to get index as well as the value for that index together.

Also, you return `nope` in the first row itself, if the string is not found there, you should only return `nope` after the complete for loop has ended, in which case you didn't find any match.

Example -

```
def search_cell(string):
    with open('aanmaningen.chr', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                if string in column:
                    print((i,j))
                    return (i,j)
    print('nope')
    return 'nope'
```

This will return the 0 indexed row and column number where the `string` was first found , or `nope` if it was not found.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! However, you missed an indent on the if statement.

Comment: Im having a problem with the code, when I search, and I get an x and y, if I run the program another time and enter a string that does not exist, it returns the result of the previous time I did get a correct result.

Comment: I have added a `print('nope')` , check if that gets printed.

Comment: Nevermind, I made a stupid mistake that had nothing to do with your code ;)